# How do I filter through an array of object and retain the object key name?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have some JSON data where I am attempting to filter out JSON objects that do not have a specific property.

I am able to use a [filter function from Underscore.JS](https://underscorejs.org/#filter) to successfully filter out the objects that do not have the correct property.

However, when the filter function runs, it is stripping out the key name of the object.

Here is the JSON that is used in the variable **data** in the filter function below:

```
{
    "Presentations": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 5
    },
    "Articles": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 1
    },
    "Blogs": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 61
    },
    "NewsBriefs": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 2
    },
    "SpecialInsights": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 50
    },
    "UserSelected": {
        "Frequency": null,
        "Value": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 0
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript filter function that is returning an array of objects that **must** include a property of **'Instant'**

```
newArr = _.filter(data, function(obj){
              return obj.hasOwnProperty('Instant')
          });
```

If I console.log the newArr, here is what I get:

```
[
   {
      "Instant":false,
      "Daily":false,
      "WeeklySummary":false,
      "ContentTypeId":5
   },
   {
      "Instant":true,
      "Daily":false,
      "WeeklySummary":true,
      "ContentTypeId":1
   },
   {
      "Instant":true,
      "Daily":false,
      "WeeklySummary":true,
      "ContentTypeId":61
   },
   {
      "Instant":false,
      "Daily":false,
      "WeeklySummary":false,
      "ContentTypeId":2
   },
   {
      "Instant":false,
      "Daily":false,
      "WeeklySummary":false,
      "ContentTypeId":50
   }
]
```

As you can see, it is correctly filtering out objects that do not have the `Instant` property which in this case is the `UserSelected` object.

However, in that process I am losing the Object key names like `Presentations` and `Articles`.

How do I retain these key names when filtering the JSON data?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Hi, yes I can add if you would like. The output will be the same as newArr but we retain those key names like in the original JSON. 

I just didn't want to add repetitive code and muddy the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it without any library:

```
Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) => {
  return value.hasOwnProperty('Instant')
}).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  return { ...acc, [key]: value }
}, {})
```

what you did wrong was that you only kept the value while iterating over the dictionary, but never carried over the keys. You can also use the new `fromEntries` I guess, but it works the same way

Comment: You don't need the `.filter()` call: `Object.keys(data).reduce((result, current) => { if (current.hasOwnProperty("Instant")) { result[current] = Object.assign({}, input[current]); } return result; }, {})`

Comment: @grokked Hi, so when I run your code, the first Object seems to have an issue where the key for "Presentations" is put into an Object with key name of "0" and it's values are put into another object with the key name of "1". The rest of the objects look correct and the UserSelected object is indeed filtered.

Any idea why the first Object "Presentations" is being split like that?

Comment: i made a mistake in the code, forgot to add the empty object as the second argument in the reduce function

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I thought it had something to do with not setting an initial value.

Comment: @Andreas you are right, but your code does not work, you should either use `data[current].hasOwnProperty("Instant")` or `Object.entries`

Comment: @grokked You're absolutely right. Looks like I've mixed two solutions... The correct version: `Object.keys(data).reduce((result, current) => { if (data[current].hasOwnProperty("Instant")) { result[current] = Object.assign({}, data[current]); } return result; }, {})`